# How can I fix array with binary?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a problem. I am going to post data to the API, but I am having problems.
The problem is that you need to post a variable that is an array in the data, but it does not work like a normal array.
When I define this normally in the code below, it works fine, but I have to do it with append because of the img_url.

```
  const datac:any = {
    lang: form.value.lang === null ? 'tr' : form.value.lang,
    name: form.value.name,
    img_url: bankImg?.value?.files[0].name,
    account_name: form.value.account_name,
    swift_code: form.value.swift_code,
    details: form.value.details
  }
```

The above details are an array and it works fine
This is the situation below, I want it to work smoothly by sending it as above.

```
  const data = new FormData()

  // const ads = bankImg.value?.value?.files[0]
  if (bankImg.value)
    data.append('img_url', bankImg.value.files[0])

  data.append('lang', form.value.lang === null ? 'tr' : form.value.lang)
  data.append('name', form.value.name)
  data.append('account_name', form.value.account_name)
  data.append('branch_name', form.value.branch_name)
  data.append('swift_code', form.value.swift_code)
  data.append('details', JSON.stringify(form.value.details));
  // const detailsArray = form.value.details;
```

Comment: As long as the form was submitted with an event chain that traces back somewhere to a user click, you should be able to use javascript to be able to capture all of the file data and process and utilize it as you wish. Please read about the `FileReader` API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader. The `bankImg?.value?.files` is a list of `File` objects, which is basically a fancy handle to a file. In old web design (like php), the php runtime and browser would handle it automatically. But in modern design, you can use js to capture, process and submit the file to api.